# Pluralization in Rails… what for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that macros like `has_many` in Rails use pluralization. What i wasnt able to find is a reason for that behavior. If I have a class `Number`, i'd write `has_many :numbers`, but where is the benefit of it? I mean, im talking about a program, not a poem.

Does 'number' state "Im ref to a scalar" and' numbers' state "Im an array"…?

From what i've seen in the [sourecode](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord) of has_many, im not shure where the translation from plural to singular occures and if it is possible to instead use a different approach for my own code. Is it possible to have ActiveRecord just use singular forms or – lets say – pluralize to §singular to mark a collection without breaking string.pluralize capabillity?

Comment: it's for readability... a poem is more readable than a program :)

Comment: But we're talking 'bout an interpreted language, isn't it? So your benefit in readability renders as another step in interpretation and threrefore is a performance malus?

Comment: Most of the performance overhead you are talking about takes place during the boot process (when all the methods are generated). After that it is just Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple linguistic cue as to whether you are dealing with a collection or a single instance. It just removes much mental churn as you don't have to consciously think about collection vs. instance.

Comment: So instead of just adding some symbol like @ in Perl that is a simple char match, ruby adds the overhead of complicated multi-lingual (think of classnames in German, Swedish or Swaheli) pluralization just for the purpose of saying: "im a collecion"?

Comment: First, `@` is a special character in Ruby. Second, It's considered a good practice to write your code in English as this allows other people to read/review/correct it.

Comment: Writing code in another language doesnt stop people from editing it. Writing it in – lets say – chinese would even increase the number of people able to read it… :-Δ

Comment: True, but in Europe (and in China for that matter) there are simply to many different languages (and dialects). Writing in non-English actually decreases the approachability of your code (not because it's written in English but because English has become the de facto standard language in technology). The most important thing is the (developer) community's ability to communicate efficiently across borders, nationalities, etc. From that rises the need for a standard language. Also note that I'm not a native English speaker/writer.

Comment: This is a very "open-sourceic" POV. In real world applications, you often find yourself coding classes out of the customers business model. Translating them into english is sometimes not just a bad idea, it could also break the agreement!

Comment: True, it is an opensource based idea. But any codebase should atleast be treated as if it is opensource. As this improves the learning curve for new team members.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby, and by extension Rails strive to be programmer friendly. An important part of that is having human readable code, therefore Rails developers have made it so that you would have a plural name where plain English calls for a plural.

It also helps to distinguish between a single object and a collection of objects, at first glance. Makes it a lot easier to read somebody else's code.

Comment: ah…? What about classes `news`, `status` or classes that named in plural-form for purpose? Programmer-friendly would be something that is easy, consistent and unique, like: (single-object:) object, (collection:) object[], (single-object from collection:) object[2]…

Comment: That's more a fallacy of English rather than Rails. "News" is an uncountable form, and "status" is a Latin loanword whose plural "statii" has never made its way across the channel.

Comment: Thats what I mean: in english usage, news may be uncountable; for me as a programmer that just created a news-object, it clearly _is_ countable. So having the interpreter telling me what im allowed to count by sheer usage of an inconsistent illogical _human_ language simply is the wrong way to do things.

By the way, the plural of status is status, just emphased with long u.

Comment: In any case, these are not language features, and impose no limits on how you can choose your class names. It just happens to be the way the majority of the Ruby community prefers to write their code. You by any means don't have to conform. Feel free to code away with newses and statuses. :)